# Entity Framework: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have a User table, with a many-to-many relationship to an Alerts table. After creating a Membership user, I am adding some extra info into the database.

```
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)   {
User user = new MidTier.Models.User();
user.FullName = model.FullName;
if (Alerts.Count() > 0)
  {
    var userAlerts = SetAlert(Alerts); // creates an IEnumerable of Alerts (from a list of int )
    foreach (var alert in userAlerts)
         {
            user.Alerts.Add(alert);                  //add each alert to the user
          }                    
   }
   userRepository.Add(user); //throwing error
   userRepository.Save();
}
```

I get an error (' **An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**') on calling the Add method. there are lots of references about this error on the net even here on SO, but after reading all those comments and suggestions, I a havent found a solution or the reason I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are lots of references about
>   this error on the net even here on SO,
>   but after reading all those comments
>   and suggestions, I a havent found a
>   solution or the reason I am getting
>   this error.

If you really searched you should already know that error says you that some entity in object graph is already attached to other context. Because of that your code sample is mostly not related. The real important code is wrapped in your methods - probably `SetAlerts` and `userRepository.Add`. If these two methods use internally context and they don't use the same instance it is the reason for your exception.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Thanks, as a reference here's what i did: In the SetAlerts method, I had a query to get the Alerts (AlertType alert = alertRepository.First(a=>a.ID== alertId); ). I needed to Detach that alert (alertRepository.Detach(alert);). I am using a Generic Repository class, (http://blog.inetux.net/post/Entity-Framework-4-Series-Generic-Repository.aspx)

Comment: Now, when I save, it creates a new User as well as a new alert. I have added that as a different question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533440/entity-framework-many-to-many-relationship