# Entity Framework: Many to Many Relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many, repository-pattern

I have two tables with a Many-To-Many relationship like this:

User(**emailaddress**, Name)

UserAlerts(**emailaddress**, **AlertId**)

Alert(**AlertId**,Title)

Alerts have already been added to the database. When inserting a new user, I am doing a lookup on the `AlertRepository`. The problem is, Instead of creating a record in the **User** and the **UsertAlerts** tables only, its also adding an extra **Alert** record.

I am using the following code:

```
public ActionResult Register(UserModel model, int[] Alerts)
User user = new MidTier.Models.User();
user.Name = model.Name;
user.EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress;    
if (Alerts!=null)
      {             
         IRepository<Alert> alertRepository = new AlertRepository();
         foreach (int alertId in Alerts)
            {
              Alert alert = alertRepository.First(a=>a.ID== alertId); 
              alertRepository.Detach(alert);  
               if (alert != null)
                  {
                    alert.Enabled = true; 
                      user.Alerts.Add(alert);
                   }                         
             }  

       }
  userRepository.Attach(user);
  userRepository.Add(user);
  userRepository.Save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to search little bit before you ask a question? This problem is asked several times per week. In your previous question I said you that you should use same context for loading `Alert` and storing `User`. You didn't do it and complicated whole situation.

The context doesn't know anything about existence of the alert. Once you call `Add` for user it will add all entities which are not tracked yet. There are three ways to solve this:

- Use the same context in both repositories and do not detach alerts. Because of loading alerts, context will know about their existence and doesn't insert them again.
- If you don't use the same context for loading you must attach the `Alert` to the new context before you add it to `User`. That is hard to do when you wrap EF code to repositories.
- If you don't use the same context and you will not attach `Alert` to the new context before you add it to `User` you must modify your `Add` method for `User` and after adding `User` to the context you must iterate every alert and change its state to `Unchanged`.